# I am writing a Vector Class in C++ using Arrays.

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

In the pop_back function I want to return the last element and delete it. If I try to delete(m_array[m_size - 1]) I am getting C2541 :delete cannot delete objects that are not pointers.
What is the correct way to delete the last element from the array?

```
 template <typename T>
 class mvector
 {

 private:

     T *m_array;
     int m_size;
     int m_reserved_size;


     public:

       T pop_back();   // decrease length by 1, returning the value removed from the vector

  };

   //Function Definition :

    template <typename T>
    T mvector<T>::pop_back()
    {
        delete(m_array[m_size - 1]);
        m_size--;
        return m_array[m_size - 1];

    }
```

Comment: Can't you just `m_size--` which would make it look like the item was deleted. You don't really need to delete it do you?

Comment: Yes, I think I will simply do that and overwrite the contents on a push_back(). That solved it. Thankyou

Comment: note: this `pop_back` is not exception-safe; if the copy of `T` made during the return throws, then the element is irretrievably lost.   For this reason, containers tend to have `void pop_back()`, and the caller would access the last element via `back()` and then call `pop_back` once they have retrieved the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, you're attempting to delete the last item, then you reduce the size and return the new last item. This would return the second to last item in the array.

Correct way would be to make a copy of the last item, reduce the size, then return the copy of the item.

```
template<typename T>
T pop_back()
{
  T ret = m_array[m_size - 1];
  m_size--;
  return ret;
}
```

You can't reduce the size of a dynamically allocated array, it needs to be reallocated.

```
T* newArray = new T[m_size];
std::copy(m_array, m_array + m_size, newArray);
delete[] m_array;
m_array = newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to partially return a block of allocated memory; it is all or nothing. Future C++ standards (C++17) might change this.

You'll have to allocate a new block of the correct size, copy everything over that you want to keep, and delete the entire old block.